# Cardinality of $A$ infinite implies $|A| = n|A|$, for $n\ge 2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $\aleph_0\le |A|$. Show that $|A| = n|A|$ for any $2\le n\in\mathbb{N}$.

My approach:

We have that $\mathbb{N}\preceq A$, which means that there exists an injective function $f:\mathbb{N}\to A$. Need to show that $A\sim \{1,\dots,n\}\times A$.

Define $g:\{1,\dots,n\}\times A \to A$ as follows:

- for $a\in A, n\in\mathbb{N}$, $g((n,a))=a$

Then $g\left(n,f(n)\right)=f(n)$, $g^{-1}\left(f(n)\right)=(n,f(n))$. Thus $g(n,f(n))$ is a bijection, so that $A\sim \{1,\dots,n\}\times A$, which implies that $|A|=n|A|$.

Please let me know if my proof is correct.

Comment: $g\circ f$ is not defined at all, because the codomain of $f$ is not the same as the domain of $g$...

Comment: I think you're right, this function should be expressed in some different way, such as $g(n, f(n))$. Editing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $\aleph_0\leq |A|$. It is enough to show for any two cardinals $|x|, |y|$ where $|x|\leq |y|$ and assuming $|y|$ is an infinite cardinal that the following holds true, 
$$|x||y|=|y|$$ 
*proof:* $$|y|\leq |x||y|\leq |y||y|=|y|^2=|y|.$$
Here we made use of the fact that $|y|^2=|y|$ for infinite cardinals.

Since we assumed $\aleph_0\leq |A|$, by the above result it must hold true for any $n\in \omega$, (i.e. the finite cardinals) that $n|A|=|A|$.

Comment: Can you please clarify: are $x$ and $y$ two sets? Also, what exactly is $\omega$?

Comment: Yes, $x$ and $y$ are sets. $\omega$ is the set of all finite ordinal and has cardinality $\aleph_0$, it is bijectively equivalent to the natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct.  The function $h(n)=g(n,f(n))$ is a function $\mathbb{N}\to A$, not a function $\{1,\dots,n\}\times A\to A$.  You have also not given any proof that this function is a bijection (and in fact it probably isn't, since it is actually the same function as $f$ and you only assumed $f$ is injective).

Comment: But $f$ is an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$, so $g(n, f(n)) = g(n, a)$, for some $a\in A$. Why is it not true that $g$ takes $\{1,\dots, n\}\times A$ to $A$? Then also we can take $f(n)=a$ back to $(n, f(n))=(n,a)$. I'm probably not seeing something, but this seems quite plausible for now.

Comment: I suggest you write down _exactly_ what function you are claiming is a bijection and try to prove that this function is both injective and surjective.  You have not done this anywhere and it seems you are confusing and conflating several different functions.